# How to get object from has_many of has_many relations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got models to call Task and User

In Task Model I reference the task its-self like below

```
belongs_to :parent, optional: true, class_name: "Task"
has_many :children, class_name: "Task",foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

In the User model, one user can have many assigned tasks.

```
has_many :tasks, foreign_key: "assignee"
```

So in case, I want to render a children tasks of tasks which are assigned for a user. What should I do?
I use

```
@children_tasks = @user.tasks.children
```

But it does not work as I expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search for tasks that has parent equal to the users tasks.

Try : `Task.where(parent: @user.tasks)`